# Defining Data Types in Excel and Building them in C#

Tags: c#, excel, data-structures

I have excel spread sheets that define data types and then provide the data for these types. The excel file has a sheet for the classes, enums and data. I'm trying to read in the data in C# and export it as json and use it in unreal. I was planning to build a tree data structure to represent the data but I'm having some trouble.

Example excel sheet

```
Struct      Type                    Name
Person      
           String                   Name
           int                       Age
           TMap<string, Person>    Children
```

I have a simple class structure like the one below I'm trying to use. The problem is with the MapNode. In the excel file there is a tab called define which maps the data columns to the class members. For example

```
    A         B
1 Name      Person::Name::Value
2 Age       Person::Age
3 ChildName Person::Children$Key::Value
4 Child     Person::Children$Value::Value
```

I can build the data structure of the classes in excel but when I try to map the data to it I'm running into issues with my map class. I'm unsure how to structure my map because it needs to support complex and simple types.

The problem is how to store children inside the map class. I originally thought of using a string -> Node dictionary, but the key can be a user defined type, object, etc; so I created the MapEntryNode. When using the define sheet mentioned above, I cannot find a good way to know which node to get out of my map of children because it only has the name of the data type not the member.

```
public class AddChildNode
{
    public string Name;
    public string Value;
    public string Type;
    public DataNode Key;
    public DataNode ValueNode;
}
public class DataNode
{
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public string Type = string.Empty;
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public virtual bool IsNode(string key) { return key == Name; }
    public virtual void AddChild(AddChildNode childData) { }
    public virtual bool GetChild(string key, out DataNode outChild)
    {
        outChild = null;
        return false;
    }
}

public class TypeNode : DataNode
{
    public Dictionary<string, DataNode> Children { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, DataNode>();

    public override void AddChild(AddChildNode childObjectData)
    {
        Children.Add(childObjectData.Name, new DataNode { Name = childObjectData.Name, Value = childObjectData.Value });
    }

    public override bool GetChild(string key, out DataNode outChild)
    {
        return Children.TryGetValue(key, out outChild);

    }
}
public class ArrayNode : DataNode
{
     public Dictionary<string, DataNode> Children { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, DataNode>();

    public override void AddChild(AddChildNode childObjectData)
    {
        Children.Add(childObjectData.Name, new DataNode { Name = childObjectData.Name, Value = childObjectData.Value });
    }

    public override bool GetChild(string key, out DataNode outChild)
    {
        return Children.TryGetValue(key, out outChild);

    }
}

public class MapNode : DataNode
{
    public Dictionary<string, MapEntryNode> Children { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, MapEntryNode>();

    public string KeyType { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public MapEntryNode Params { get; set; }

    public MapNode(string name, string keyType, string ValueType)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.KeyType = keyType;
        this.ValueType = ValueType;
        Type = "Map";
        Params = new MapEntryNode();
    }

    public override void AddChild(AddChildNode childObjectData)
    {
        Params.AddChild(childObjectData);
    }

    public override bool GetChild(string key, out DataNode outChild)
    {
        return Params.GetChild(key, out outChild);
    }
}

public class MapEntryNode : DataNode
{
    public Dictionary<string, DataNode> Children { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, DataNode>();

    public DataNode Key { get; set; }
    public DataNode ValueNode { get; set; }

    public override bool GetChild(string key, out DataNode outChild)
    {
        outChild = null;
        if (key == ValueNode.Name)
        {
            outChild = ValueNode;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public override void AddChild(AddChildNode childObjectData)
    {
        Children.Add(childObjectData.Key.Name, childObjectData.ValueNode);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or advice?

Comment: Could you be more clear on "running into issues with my map class"? It's hard to say what's wrong without an exact problem.

Comment: I added some more information. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: The question is unclear because none of the things you describe exists in Excel. These are all concepts in your own code. Excel has no nodes, no objects or children, and only a few basic types, so it's unclear what the code you posted is meant to do or even how Excel is involved. How do you read the data in the first place? If you use `ExcelDatatReader` for example, you get an IDbDataReader the same way you would from a database query. It's up to you then to map each row to an object and assign each field's value to a property. That's not hard to do in a loop .

Comment: If you read Excel data as an IDataReader you can use FastMember's [Parse](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Dapper/SqlMapper.IDataReader.cs#L14) to map fields to classes by name with a single call, eg `var persons=reader.Parse<Person>();`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I read the data using the Microsoft excel library. The question is about structuring my data to be able to read custom defined types from excel and build them in C#.

Comment: There's no Microsoft excel library. Either you used Excel Interop to actually control an Excel instance, used the Jet OLEDB driver to read the data, or used the low-level OpenXML SDK to read elements at slightly above XML level, or some other library. None of these has classes like those you posted. And Excel has no custom types.

Comment: Repeating what you wrote in the question as a comment won't help. The question remains unclear and the assumptions wrong. Excel still has no custom types. You're trying to read flat Excel data in some unspecified way. You've stored some strings that define how that flat data needs to be mapped to `Person` and `Child` objects. All those Node-derived classes seem to be an attempt to create a mapper from the flat data to actual objects. That's all your own custom code and conventions. We can't help with code you haven't posted.

Comment: It's unclear even what the Excel data look like. If the data came in an Excel table with proper columns, I'd use `ExcelDataReader` to read the data and FastMember's `Parse` to quickly map the columns to object properties by name. If there are no column names or I don't like them, I'd pass them explicitly to ExcelDataReader. For more complex cases, I'd loop over the results and create an instance of the class I want by reading field values and assigning them to properties.

Comment: Or I'd pass the `IDataReader` created by ExcelDataReader directly to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` and insert all data at once into a staging table, and clean it up using SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added an example of how the types are defined in excel. As I mentioned in the question, I define these types in excel and then read them in and try to create them in the node objects. Yes, I am using Interop to read the data. I have columns to define the name of the struct, the type of the fields and the name of them. I don't have these classes defined in my code anywhere. I'm just trying to read the excel data, parse it and export it as json to be used inside unreal engine.